# jQuery Validate plugin, enable submit button when form is valid without eager validation

Tags: jquery

In my case I have variety of elements such as input, select, checkbox, radio. Is there any way to find out if form is valid and enable submit button. Currently what I am doing is, calling .valid() method to find form's validity which is triggering validation for elements and showing error messages as soon as I click on any element which I want to avoid.

Comment: can you please provide fiddle it will be easy to solve your problem

Comment: maybe you can have a look at the jquery form validation plugin? http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: here it is, http://jsfiddle.net/maheshambiga/b1dL20e0/

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for such solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("input.submit").prop("disabled", true);
  
  $('form').validate({
 showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {

  var formSelector = '#' + this.currentForm.id;
  var formObject = $(formSelector);
  var validateObject = formObject.validate();
  var numberOfInvalids = validateObject.numberOfInvalids();

  if(numberOfInvalids == 0)
  $("input.submit").prop("disabled", false);
  else
  $("input.submit").prop("disabled", true);
      
    }
 });
    
 $("#commentForm").valid();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
 <fieldset>
 <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>
 <p>
 <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
 <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required>
 </p>
 <p>
 <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
 <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required>
 </p>
 <p>
 <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
 <input id="curl" type="url" name="url">
 </p>
 <p>
 <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
 <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
 </p>
 <p>
 <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" >
 </p>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```